# Trying to create a linear regression in R where the dependent variable is newly created, and its values are determined by other variables in dataset?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to create a new variable, Commuting Costs (from location A to B), that is determined by commuting time, age, number of children, education attainment, and gender. I only have data for the predictor variables. I want to make a linear regression with Commuting Costs as my independent variable, but I'm not sure how to do that since I have no data on Commuting Costs.

Can I just add them all together to create the new variable.

```
mydata$CommutingCosts <- commuting time + age + number of children + education attainment + gender
```

And then follow with a linear regression to determine my coefficients?

```
fit <- lm(CommutingCosts ~ commuting time + age + number of children + education attainment + gender, data = mydata)
```

Comment: It's not possible to add apples with oranges and say we have bananas. You are adding commuting time with age, number of children etc. and computing commuting costs. Its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing does not make sense. If you want to use regression analysis with response variable `CommutingCosts`, then you need ro go out and get some data for that variable!

The way you propose it, you calculate `CommutingCosts` as a sum of a bunch of variables, and regression analysis will only give you back the coefficients 1 you used in that sum.

By the way, your question is not about a specific programming problem, so not really on-topic here!

Comment: Got it. That's what I suspected.  The CommutingCosts came from a theoretical model that used selected variables suspected to increase costs.  I was trying to figure out a way to quantify it using the variables I had. Thanks

Comment: If the answer helped you, you could help the site by upvoting/accepting it.